# Traversing Multi Dimensional Arrays

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to get to the 'id' by looping through the multidimensional array '$ll10_violations'.  How would I do that?

```
<?php echo $html->link('View Violation', '/violations/editllviolation/' . 
$ll10_violations[0]['Ll10Violation']['id']) ?>
```

Thanks,

CM

Comment: What is the structure of `$ll10....`?

Comment: I am trying to track that down now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just have to use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($ll10_violations as $viloation){
    // Code here....
    // Access data like this $violation['key']
}
```

If you are not sure how, post your array structure and I'll help you out

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi Bounya I figured it out.